# « Une chanson trop songée ». Que veut dire « songée » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, québec, art

Dans la serie télé *Unité-9* à Radio-Canada, [un personnage dit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kwo2IG5gRtc):

> [...] une chanson un peu triste que toutes les filles aimaient et que tous les gars trouvaient un peu trop songée [...]

J'ai cherché les mots *songée* et *songer* dans plusieurs dictionnaires et je n'arrive pas a comprendre ce que ça veut dire dans ce contexte.

Comment: On pourrait y voir un parallélisme avec l'anglais *to overthink something* ([def](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/overthink)), non ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dans des cas comme celui-ci, *songé* ne fait pas référence à un songe ou un rêve (ou même à l'anglais « *song* »), mais plutôt à la définition de penser, réfléchir longuement du verge *songer*. Très utilisé au Québec, le Multidictionnaire de la langue française de Marie-Éva de Villers le caractérise en fait d'impropriété dans son sens habituellement utilisé de **intelligent, ingénieux, astucieux**.

Comment: *Très utilisé au Québec*, et *seulement* au Québec. Cette extension de sens n'est a priori pas utilisée ailleurs.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez A priori, certes, mais je ne peux affirmer avec certitude qu'elle est utilisée au Québec. Je serais mal à l'aise d'affirmer qu'elle est utilisée *seulement* au Québec alors que je n'ai jamais mis les pieds dans une des nombreuses autres sociétés francophones sur la planète.

Answer (score 5):

Je ne sais pas si c'est spécifiquement du français canadien, mais ça veut dire grosso modo "trop intellectuel, auquel on a trop réfléchi". On emploie de même "songé" au sens de "bien pensé, mûrement réfléchi".